# $f\left(x\right)\:$ is a function that is defined for all $x\neq 0$ . Does $\lim _{x\to 0}\left(xf\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)$ exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

I couldn't think about a counterexample but I cannot just assume that it is true. Can someone help with a counterexample or the proof?

Comment: Do you mean $x\ne0$?

Comment: By exist do you mean that it must equal a real number?

Comment: The function $f(x) = x^2$ is defined for all $x \not= 0$, yet $xf(1/x))=1/x$ does not have a limit at $x=0$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. but $x^2$ is also defined at $x=0$

Comment: Being defined everywhere implies that it is defined on the set $\{x\in\mathbb R : x\neq 0\}$. If you meant to say that $f$ has no continuous extension to $\mathbb R$, you should add this to your question

Comment: @HouseBT you didn't insist that $f$ is undefined at $x=0$.  If you do, you could take $f(x) = x^3/x$. Perhaps you want $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ not to exist?

Comment: Are you insisting that $f$ has a non-removable singularity at $0$?

Comment: @K.Power No, I'm not. Thank you.

Comment: Then @UmbertoP's example should suffice.

Comment: The restriction is not so interesting anyway because for $x$ small, $1/x$ is huge. So the value of $f$ at 0 plays no role at all. In any case, the function $x^2 + 1/x^2$ also works.

Answer (score 4):

The limit exists if and only if both $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}$ exist and are equal (it's an interesting exercise).

Now the example should be easy: take $f(x)=x\sin x$. If you want that $f$ is not defined nor has a continuous extension at $0$, consider $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}+x\sin x$.

Direct proof:
$$
xf\Bigl(\frac{1}{x}\Bigr)=x\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\sin\frac{1}{x}\right)=x^2+\sin\frac{1}{x}
$$
has no limit for $x\to0$.

Comment: Wow. We have a counterexample. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not. Let $f(x) =|x|.$ Then $xf(1/x) = 1$ for $x>0,$ $xf(1/x) = -1$ for $x<0.$ Hence the limit in question does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not defined $f(x)$, I can only answer this question in a general way.

The argument of $\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is $\frac{1}{x}$ which, when $x$ approaches zero, approaches infinity. So, if $f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is a bounded function near infinity, then the solution will always be zero.

Lastly, in the indeterminate case of $f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ approaching infinity, there could be a possible solution, which would require L'Hospital's Rule to solve if it exists. This would have the $0.\infty$ indeterminate form. You could rewrite this in a $\frac{0}{0}$ form or a $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ form and apply L'Hospital's Rule. This rule basically states that, for either of these two forms, the limit exists if the limits of the numerator and denominator exists and the limit of the denominator is not zero. The limit is then equal to the ratio of the limits of the derivatives. This can be written as follows:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow k} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\lim_{x \rightarrow k}f'(x)}{\lim_{x \rightarrow k}g'(x)}$$

The fact that $f(x)$ is not defined at $x = 0$ does not affect this question at all since its argument is moving away from zero.